# how select only the first node of a type, in next siblings with mechanize? (ruby)

Tags: css, ruby, nokogiri, selector, mechanize

```
<div></div>
<p>foo</p>
<ul><li>bar</li></ul>
<ul><li>baz</li></ul>
```

How can I select first ul only? (using Mechanize like `page = Mechanize.new.get(url)`)

if I try :

`page.at('div').at('+ ul li').inner_html`, it's `nil` because `<ul>` is not immediat sibling

`page.at('div').search('~ ul').first.at('li').inner_html` it's ok but `~ ul` will get all next `<ul>` and it's a lost time because I need only the first and it's possible there is lot of `<ul>`...

So there is an alternative?

Comment: Are you able to use CSS pseudo selectors? If you are, then `page.at('div').search('~ ul:first-of-type').first.at('li').inner_html` or `page.at('div').at('ul:first-of-type li').inner_html` should work?

Comment: nice, it works. I thougth pseudo class css doesn't works in this case ! ^^

Post the answer ;)

Comment: Awesome :) Glad it helped! Have added it as an answer :) Was unsure as I have no mechanize experience...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are targeting through the DOM you can use the `:first-of-type` pseudo selector like this:

```
page.at('div').search('~ ul:first-of-type').first.at('li').inner_html
```

or

```
page.at('div').at('ul:first-of-type li').inner_html
```